# Understanding left hand notation of C(n,2)= n(n−1)​ / 2

Tags: algorithm, math, notation

> For an array of n integers, there are C(n,2)= n(n−1)​ / 2 pairs of
> integers. Thus, we may check all n(n−1)​ / 2 pairs and see if there is
> any pair with duplicates.

I was poking around a LeetCode question and the answer for one of the algorithms included the above formula in the question explanation.

What is the point of the `C(n, 2)` nomenclature on the left hand side of the equation? Is this a known/named standard that I can read and interpret, or is this some more general information that must/should be ascertained from context? I understand the math on the right, but I don't have any preconceived notions that adds any detail to my understanding from the function on the left.

What is the 2 doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), or "nCk" or "n Choose k".

The formula is [image]

Here *n* is the size of the set, and *k* = 2 is the number of elements to select, so that e.g. sets `{3, 6}` and `{6,3}` taken are considered equal.

AFAIK, the standard notation in combinatorics is as shown above and spelled "n choose k", where as `C(...)` is non-standard requiring clarification when first introduced.

Comment: MathJax does not seem to work. Working  on that.

Comment: MathJax is only available on [cs.se] and [math.se] (and maybe some other similar sites). This question should have been directed to [math.se], where MathJax would have been available.

Comment: Related: [mathjax](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396502/mathjax-in-2020-ce)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I had a suspicion that this had to do with the notation surrounding combinatorics (given the explanation), but I did not want to assume. Thanks! (Likewise, I updated the post categorization. My apologies.)